# How do I create a new MetropolisUI item in a Delphi TListBox at runtime?

Tags: delphi, listbox

I'm trying to add a feature to a program that allows the user to add a new TMetropolisUIListBoxItem to a TListBox while the program is running, in a way that the title, subtitle and short description of the item are customized by using three TEdit components.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
procedure TEdit1.EditButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  C : TMetropolisUIListBoxItem;
begin
  C := TMetropolisUIListBoxItem.Create(Self);
  C.Description := Edit1.Text;
  C.SubTitle := Edit2.Text;
  C.Title := Edit3.Text;
end;
```

But I don't see how can I create it INSIDE of the TListbox.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you using VCL or Firemonkey?

Comment: Don't you add the item just like you would any other to an FMX control?

Comment: Probably 'listbox1.addobject(c)'. I think owner of the item should be the box.

Comment: Pascal does not have a class called `TMetropolisUI` or anything related to it, so I've removed the Pascal tag. This question is specific to Delphi. Please only use tags that are actually applicable to your question, so it gets to the attention of those who can answer it (and not to others who can't), and so that it is classified correctly when searching by tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign listbox1 to the parent property of the created item:

```
procedure TEdit1.EditButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  C : TMetropolisUIListBoxItem;
begin
  C := TMetropolisUIListBoxItem.Create(Self);
  C.Description := Edit1.Text;
  C.SubTitle := Edit2.Text;
  C.Title := Edit3.Text;
  C.Parent := listbox1;
end;
```